# how to redirect to controller from global.asax when session end in mvc 4 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

how to redirect to controller from global.asax when session end.

when session end i want to redirect to controller from global.asax using mvc 4 c#.
I am trying the below code.but not working.any suggestions.

Here is my Global.asax.

```
 void Session_OnEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
                Response.RedirectToRoute("logout", "Home");           
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try like this,

```
void Session_OnEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Home/logout");         
}
```

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Response is not available in this context.

Comment: i am checking but same issue is showing:
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MyZefer.UI.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.